"slither" or "sliver"?
Does the speaker here say "slither" or "sliver"?
https://youtube.com/clip/UgkxObxCtcUGP0YrZnTWdXeVmgf1jjtSez60?si=vRIE5-qm4dAzhcVm
Looking at the context it seems that it's "sliver" but the way she pronounces it hints at "slither" and the subtitles confirm that it's "slither". Which is very confusing.
Would appreciate any help with this.

I'm not gonna go listen. Who cares if the speaker misspoke? The intended word should be contextually obvious, since slither is a verb with a very different meaning to the noun sliver.

The speaker does say slither, it's the British (mistaken) variant of sliver. OED says it means:

Something smooth and slippery; a smoothly sliding mass; = sliver n.1 1.

Calvin Klein's newest dress is a slither of silk shaped simply like an overgrown T-shirt.


Google Books finds it used by English authors. But it is much less common than the idiomatic sliver of hope.
EDIT: According to this excellent answer of @Matt E. Эллен it is in fact a misspelling/mispronunciation of sliver and it passed into written texts. So, well-spotted, it should definitely be sliver of hope.

Does the speaker have a Scottish accent? The full OED specifically notes it as Scottish, and their most recent citation is 140 years ago anyway. Besides which, the definition is (plural) ‘Loose stones lying in great quantities on the side of a rock or hill’. No mention of metaphoric transfer, so it's screamingly obvious to me the speaker has simply mispronounced sliver.

OxfordL also includes it: informal•British/a sliver: "a slither of bacon".

That sounds truly disgusting to me! (And ignorant, obviously! :)

@FumbleFingers It may well sound this way to you, but people have started using it even in writing, which is why I find it pertinent to signal it as a mistake here.

Well, I suppose a foodie might not mind speaking of oysters slithering down the throat, but slithery / slippery bacon sliding around the plate isn't an image I'd want to call to mind when tucking into a good British breakfast! Having said that, as a student I knew a folk musician who wrote a humorous song about Pont L'eveque French cheese (a mysterious substance that slithered and slid around the plate! Not to be confused with Crotte du diable :)
